# How to sort variables in an xsl for-each list

Tags: asp.net, xslt

I have the following code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="PriceSelect_{$ModuleId}" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical"  NOWRAP="TRUE">
  <xsl:for-each select="Page/ArrayOfWebPrice/WebPrice">
    <xsl:variable name ="RateCode" select ="RateCode"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name ="RateStructure" select ="RateStructure"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name ="Price" select="concat($CurrencySymbol, format-number(Price, concat('#,###,##0.', substring($zeros, 1, $CurrencyPrecision))), ' ', $CurrencyCode)"></xsl:variable>
    <asp:ListItem  value="{$RateStructure}_{$RateCode}_Price" Enabled ="true" Selected ="true" text="{$Price}" >
    </asp:ListItem>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <asp:ListItem  value="Other" Enabled ="true" Selected ="false">
  </asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I am trying to sort the order of each list item, which are numbers.

Comment: Have you examined the `<xsl:sort>` function? http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting

Comment: So what have you tried so far? http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I've tried using the <xsl:sort> but I may be inserting it in the wrong place or using the wrong variables. This file is pulling from a DNN module.

Comment: Show us your source document, and show us your attempt to use xsl:sort, and your desired output; then we can see where you are going wrong.